# My code of ruby is error to syntax please help me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I build a class of mother is "animal" and build a child class.
I do Inheritance from child class to mother class but something wrong in my code and I have to fix this but not good please help me I am a newbie

```
class Animal
def initialize
    @name = "DigDok"
    @age = 20
    @sex = "male"
end
end
module Detail
def detail_set
    @detail.join(',')
end
    class Bird < Animal
        def initialize
            @detail = {
                :wing => 2
                :legs => 2
            }
        end
    end

    class Mammal < Animal
        def initialize
            @detail = {
                :legs => 4
                :babyfood => "Milk"
                :special_ability => nil
            }
        end
    end

    class Cat < Animal
        def initialize
            @detail = {
                :sharpclaws => "very Sharp"
                :special_ability => "Climb a tree"
            }
        end
    end

    class Dog < Animal
        def initialize
            @detail = {
                :best_friend => "Human"
                :special_ability => "Bark"
            }
        end
    end
 end
```

but run in irb terminal Result is

```
SyntaxError: ./learningruby.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}'
                    :legs => 2
                     ^
./learningruby.rb:30: class definition in method body
./learningruby.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}'
                    :babyfood => "Milk"
                     ^
./learningruby.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND
                    :special_ability => nil
                                       ^
./learningruby.rb:40: class definition in method body
./learningruby.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}'
                    :special_ability => "Climb a tree"
                     ^
./learningruby.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
./learningruby.rb:49: class definition in method body
./learningruby.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}'
                    :special_ability => "Bark"
                     ^
./learningruby.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

sorry if my question so long but thank...

Comment: You need a comma between hashes: `wing:2, legs:2`

Answer (score 5):

You're missing commas: `@detail = { :wing => 2, :legs => 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problem:

First, you missed many commas:

```
@detail = { :wing => 2, :legs => 2 }

@detail = { :legs => 4, :babyfood => "Milk", :special_ability => nil }

@detail = { :sharpclaws => "very Sharp", :special_ability => "Climb a tree" }

@detail = { :best_friend => "Human", :special_ability => "Bark" }
```

Second, your `@detail` is a **hash**, you can not use **`join()` method of array**. If you want to make it become to a string, try this:

```
@detail.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join(',')
=> "wing=2,legs=2"
...
```